# What is the cheapest way to transfer files from one S3 bucket to another?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was going to straight up copy paste everything via a Commander One file manager, but turns out that's going to cost a fortune. Cuz I guess that counts as downloading and then reuploading everything. I was told to use an instance instead and transfer them that way (still trying to figure out how to do that). But are there any other simple(r) ways maybe?

trying to attach this policy to the destination bukkit:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {"AWS":"arn:aws:iam::<id number here>:user/<username here>"},
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket to get files from>/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {"AWS":"arn:aws:iam::<id number here>:user/<username here>"},
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket to put files in>"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

getting `policy has invalid resource` error

Comment: is the bucket located in the same region, and with the same account?

Comment: @alex067 same region, but different account

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `CopyObject()` command, which copies objects directly between Amazon S3 buckets with no need to download/upload. Since the buckets are in the same region, the only cost is a few API request ($0.005 per 1,000 requests).

The easiest way to do this is with the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), using either the `aws s3 cp` or `aws s3 sync` command. It will call `CopyObject()` on your behalf. For example:

```
aws s3 sync s3://bucket-a/folder/ s3://bucket-b/folder/
```

Please note that the credentials you use to perform the copy must have **read permission** on the source bucket and **write permission** on the destination bucket.

Let's say you are copying from `Bucket-A` in `Account-A` to `Bucket-B` in `Account-B`. This can be done either by:

- Using credentials from an IAM User (`User-B`) from `Account-B`. Add a **bucket policy** on `Bucket-A` allowing `User-B` to **read** from the bucket, *OR*
- Using credentials from an IAM User (`User-A`) from `Account-A`. Add a **bucket policy** on `Bucket-A` allowing `User-A` to **write** to the bucket. When copying, be sure to add `--acl bucket-owner-full-control` to grant object ownership to `Account-B`.

I prefer the first option, since the destination account is 'pulling' the files into its own account, so it owns the files by default.

Comment: The CopyObject() automatically assigns the source bucket's ownership to the destination account?

Comment: Sort of. When an object is copied, an ACL is assigned. I know from experience that if you copy to another account, the object does not "belong" to the destination account. Ironically, the owner of the bucket might not even be able to access the object, or even delete it! That's why, when copying to a _different_ account, it is important to add `--acl bucket-owner-full-control`. It will be automatic if a file is copied _from _ another bucket, because the copy was instigated from the destination account, so the destination account 'owns' the object.

Comment: Aw, man, I wish I could try this, but I can't figure out the bucket policy %\ ... please see the update.

Comment: But the ACL is only for the AWS account. You still have to define a bucket policy for that specific user, correct?

Comment: A **Bucket Policy** can only grant permission on the bucket to which it is attached. You cannot create a bucket policy that refers to two different buckets. The other permission should be assigned directly to the IAM User, which grants access in the same account as the IAM User.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do it is using sync, it's pretty straight forward:

```
aws s3 sync s3://sourcebucket s3://destinationbucket
```

Read more at: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/copy-s3-objects-account/

You also do have to adjust the bucket policies of the source and destination bucket to allow gets & puts respectively.

As for cost, if its in the same region, it's free. You are technically not transferring data out to the internet, you are transferring it to another s3 bucket within the same region.

Comment: what if I can't add a policy to the source bucket because it doesn't belong to me? >.> ... but I have the access id and secret keys for it

Comment: You mean the destination bucket. 

I'm not sure why you have CLI access but not console access, but maybe this can help you: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTpolicy.html

Comment: whatchu mean i mean the destination bucket? +.+ i definitely meant the source bucket. There are files there that I wanted to copy over to my S3, and internets said that I need to add policy to both, the source, and destination buckets

Comment: The source refers to the bucket you are copying files FROM and the destination you are copying files TO. But that's just technicalities at this point. 

When using sync to copy the bucket over, you can add a predefined acl (canned acl) that grants permissions to the destination owner over his/her new object. Use: --acl bucket-owner-full-control

Comment: so i don't need any policy for the source bucket to copy stuff from even tho it's not mine?..